# How to describe all normal subgroups of the affine group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field. Consider the group $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{F}_q)$

\begin{gathered}
\verb|Aff|\mathbb{(F_q)} := 
\
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\colon a \in \mathbb F^{*}_q, b \in \mathbb{F}_q
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}

It's easy to see that the homomorphism $\psi: \mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{F}_q) \rightarrow \mathbb F^{*}_q$ defined by
$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a$
describes some normal subgroups. Every subgroup H of $\mathbb F^{*}_q$ (which is cyclic of order q-1) is normal in $\mathbb F^{*}_q$, so we get a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ by taking the inverse image of H: the group of matrices
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\colon a \in H, b \in \mathbb{F_q}
\end{Bmatrix}
 where $H \trianglelefteq \mathbb F^{*}_q \simeq \mathbb{Z_{q-1}}$.

Is that full description?

Comment: Yes, apart from the trivial subgroup, all normal subgroups are of that form.

Comment: @DarekHolt I'm sorry, how to show that there are not other subgroups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $K:=\ker \psi = \{ \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&b\\0&1 \end{array}\right):b \in {\mathbb F}_q \}$. Also $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}a&0\\0&1 \end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}1&b\\0&1 \end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}a&0\\0&1 \end{array}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&ab\\0&1 \end{array}\right)$$
so all nontrivial elements of $K$ are conjugate in $G := {\rm Aff}({\mathbb F}_q)$. So $[G,G] = K$.

Now let any $N$ be any nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ and let $g \in N \setminus \{1\}$. Since $Z(G)=1$, there exists $h \in G$ with $[g,h] \ne 1$ and $[g,h] \in [G,G] = K$. Hence $K \le N$, and so $N$ is the inverse image under $\psi$ of a subgroup of ${\mathbb F}_q^*$.

Comment: Sorry, but the product of such matrices is 
[1 a^{-1}b]
[0       1   ]

Comment: Corrected (although that wouldn't affect the argument).

Comment: @DarekHolt Sorry, but > there exists h \in G with... do you mean there exists h \in N ?

Comment: No, $g$ was supposed to be in $N$ - i've edited it.

Comment: @DarekHolt I'm sorry, could you explain please, why does [G,G] \leq N? We showed that [N,G] \leq N because we chose g from N.

Comment: I have explained that. We have shown that $N$ contains some nontrivial element of $K$, and they are conjugate in $G$, so it must contain all of them.